# Spring JPA and Hibernate 4 with Infinispan as 2nd level cache provider

Tags: spring, hibernate, caching, jpa, infinispan

I searched on google and found a few people having the same issue but could not find a concrete answer.

Basically we use Spring with JPA along with Hibernate 4.1.7 and trying to setup Infinispan as 2nd level cache provider:

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"> 
    org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory
</prop>
```

However, during startup, I'm getting the following exception:

> Caused by: org.infinispan.CacheException: *This is transactional cache but no transaction manager could be found. Configure the transaction manager lookup properly.*

We don't use JTA but the JpaTransactionManager from Spring, I guess at runtime, Hibernate should know the existing jpaTransactionManager and uses it, however, Infinispan doesn't know it hence blow up. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any hibernate.transaction.factory_class or hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class defined?

Comment: Yes, I did added the following but didn't work. It was trying to find transactionManager from JNDI. <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory</prop> <prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup</prop>

Comment: This is how we define our transactionManager in Spring: {code}    <bean id="transactionManager" 
       class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
  <property name="defaultTimeout" value="${defaultTransactionTimeout}"/>
    </bean> {code}

Comment: Can you share a standalone project with your current codebase that we can debug through?

Comment: Ups, too early. Are you providing any custom Infinispan configuration? If you're not able to provide code to debug, you could debug the code yourself. Here's the relevant method that configures Infinispan's TransactionManager. See what's going on there :)

Comment: Forgot to add: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/4.1.7.Final/hibernate-infinispan/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cache/infinispan/InfinispanRegionFactory.java#L511